# Is it possible to generate CREATE TABLE SQL statements from an entity class for solve invalid schema error easily?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am working with a table with many columns in Android Room.

I have created the table in SQLite and the corresponding entity class in Java. And when I compile the application I have the error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_0       Process:
> com.my.app, PID: 8356         java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while
> computing database live data.             at
> androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
> at
> androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run(TransactionExecutor.java:47)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)        Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid
> schema: today(com.my.app.data.entity.TodayEntity).        Expected:
> E/AndroidRuntime: TableInfo{name='today',
> columns={liturgyFK=Column{name='liturgyFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, timeID=Column{name='timeID', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, tPrayerFK=Column{name='tPrayerFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, tHymnFK=Column{name='tHymnFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, saintFK=Column{name='saintFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, oHymnFK=Column{name='oHymnFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, nPsalmodyFK=Column{name='nPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, vPrayerFK=Column{name='vPrayerFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, nBiblicalFK=Column{name='nBiblicalFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, massReadingFK=Column{name='massReadingFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, nPrayerFK=Column{name='nPrayerFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, sPsalmodyFK=Column{name='sPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, oPrayerFK=Column{name='oPrayerFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, vMagnificatFK=Column{name='vMagnificatFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, vHymnFK=Column{name='vHymnFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, lBenedictusFK=Column{name='lBenedictusFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, lHymnFK=Column{name='lHymnFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, invitatoryFK=Column{name='invitatoryFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, lPrayerFK=Column{name='lPrayerFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, vPsalmodyFK=Column{name='vPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, oVerseFK=Column{name='oVerseFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, lPsalmodyFK=Column{name='lPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, oPsalmodyFK=Column{name='oPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, oTeDeum=Column{name='oTeDeum', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'},
> nHymnFK=Column{name='nHymnFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> oBiblicalFK=Column{name='oBiblicalFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> vIntercessionsFK=Column{name='vIntercessionsFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, lIntercessionsFK=Column{name='lIntercessionsFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, todayDate=Column{name='todayDate',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1,
> defaultValue='null'}, previousFK=Column{name='previousFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='1'}, tBiblicalFK=Column{name='tBiblicalFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, tPsalmodyFK=Column{name='tPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'   E/AndroidRuntime: },
> sHymnFK=Column{name='sHymnFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> sBiblicalFK=Column{name='sBiblicalFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> oPatristicFK=Column{name='oPatristicFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> weekDayFK=Column{name='weekDayFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> lBiblicalFK=Column{name='lBiblicalFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> vBiblicalFK=Column{name='vBiblicalFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> sPrayerFK=Column{name='sPrayerFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}},
> foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[sHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[nPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[tHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_office_verse_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oVerseFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_reading_short_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[tBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[nPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_reading_short_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[nBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[sPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_office_patristic_join',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oPatristicFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[tPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='saint',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[saintFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[saintID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='mass_reading_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[massReadingFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[liturgyFK]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='liturgy',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[previousFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[liturgyID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_reading_short_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_gospel_canticle', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lBenedictusFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_reading_short_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oPrayerFK], r    E/AndroidRuntime:
> eferenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[sPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_invitatory_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[invitatoryFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_intercessions_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lIntercessionsFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[nHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_gospel_canticle', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vMagnificatFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_intercessions_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vIntercessionsFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='liturgy',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[liturgyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[liturgyID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_office_biblical_join',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[tPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_reading_short_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[sBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]}], indices=[]}         Found:
> E/AndroidRuntime: TableInfo{name='today',
> columns={liturgyFK=Column{name='liturgyFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, timeID=Column{name='timeID', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, tPrayerFK=Column{name='tPrayerFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, tHymnFK=Column{name='tHymnFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, saintFK=Column{name='saintFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, oHymnFK=Column{name='oHymnFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, nPsalmodyFK=Column{name='nPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, vPrayerFK=Column{name='vPrayerFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, nBiblicalFK=Column{name='nBiblicalFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, massReadingFK=Column{name='massReadingFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, nPrayerFK=Column{name='nPrayerFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, sPsalmodyFK=Column{name='sPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, oPrayerFK=Column{name='oPrayerFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, vMagnificatFK=Column{name='vMagnificatFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, vHymnFK=Column{name='vHymnFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, lBenedictusFK=Column{name='lBenedictusFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, lHymnFK=Column{name='lHymnFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, invitatoryFK=Column{name='invitatoryFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, lPrayerFK=Column{name='lPrayerFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, vPsalmodyFK=Column{name='vPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, oVerseFK=Column{name='oVerseFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, lPsalmodyFK=Column{name='lPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, oPsalmodyFK=Column{name='oPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, oTeDeum=Column{name='oTeDeum', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='0'},
> nHymnFK=Column{name='nHymnFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> oBiblicalFK=Column{name='oBiblicalFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> vIntercessionsFK=Column{name='vIntercessionsFK', type='INTEGER',
> affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, lIntercessionsFK=Column{name='lIntercessionsFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, todayDate=Column{name='todayDate',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1,
> defaultValue='null'}, previousFK=Column{name='previousFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='1'}, tBiblicalFK=Column{name='tBiblicalFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'}, tPsalmodyFK=Column{name='tPsalmodyFK',
> type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0,
> defaultValue='null'   E/AndroidRuntime: },
> sHymnFK=Column{name='sHymnFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> sBiblicalFK=Column{name='sBiblicalFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> oPatristicFK=Column{name='oPatristicFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> lBiblicalFK=Column{name='lBiblicalFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> vBiblicalFK=Column{name='vBiblicalFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> sPrayerFK=Column{name='sPrayerFK', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}},
> foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[sHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[nPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[tHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_office_verse_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oVerseFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_reading_short_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[tBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[nPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_reading_short_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[nBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[sPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_office_patristic_join',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oPatristicFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[tPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='saint',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[saintFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[saintID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='mass_reading_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[massReadingFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[liturgyFK]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='liturgy', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[previousFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[liturgyID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_reading_short_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_gospel_canticle', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lBenedictusFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_reading_short_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', colum     E/AndroidRuntime: nNames=[sPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_intercessions_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lIntercessionsFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_invitatory_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[invitatoryFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_psalmody_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vPsalmodyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[nHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_hymn_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lHymnFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_intercessions_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vIntercessionsFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_gospel_canticle', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[vMagnificatFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='liturgy',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[liturgyFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[liturgyID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[tPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_office_biblical_join',
> onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[oBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_reading_short_join', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[sBiblicalFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]},
> ForeignKey{referenceTable='lh_prayer', onDelete='CASCADE',
> onUpdate='CASCADE', columnNames=[lPrayerFK],
> referenceColumnNames=[groupID]}], indices=[]}             at
> androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onCreate(RoomOpenHelper.java:82)

The error message shows the differences between the expected and the found table, but in a disordered way that difficult the comparison in a big table.

My question is if there is a way to convert an entity class to a `CREATE TABLE` statement, so that it is easier to compare the two `CREATE TABLE`  to find where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is if there is a way to convert an entity class to a CREATE TABLE statement, so that it is easier to compare the two CREATE TABLE to find where the error is.

Yes, Room does this on your behalf as it generates the SQL. Try the following:-

1. Create the `@Entity` annotated classes.
2. Incude the `@Entity` annotated classes in the `entities=` parameter of the `@Database` annotated abstract class.
3. Compile the project.
4. Using Android Studio's **Android View** locate the **java (generated)**, find the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **_Impl**.
5. Within the class locate the **createAllTables** method.
6. There will be an `_db.execSQL` statement for every table and also for indexes. You can copy and paste the SQL from these.

   1. You do not (should not) have to create the room_master_table nor use the insert into the room_master_table.

Example

[image]

Rather than compare, you may wish to use the actual SQL statements to create the table(s). If you have existing tables with data then you could rename them using an `ALTER TABLE the_table RENAME TO the_renamed_original_table;` and then after creating table(s) using the Room SQL use an INSERT INTO the_table SELECT * FROM the_renamed_original_table.

- [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)
- [`INSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)
- Note that you will have to consider Foreign Key constraints, that is that the Parents must exist unless you turn Foreign Key Support off.
- [Enabling Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable)